# Getting value from a Task crash the code in C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm nooby in C# Xamarin and I try to understand how Task works and why when I want to get the value from it crash the code.

**XAML Code:**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyFirstApp.Views.AuthPage">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Test"
                     Order="Primary"
                     Priority="0" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <WebView x:Name="Browser" Navigating="WebNavigating"></WebView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**CS code:**

```
public partial class AuthPage : ContentPage
{
    public AuthPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Browser.Source = "https://www.google.com";
    }

    private void WebNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {

        var myClass = new MyClass();
        var ctrl = myClass.MyFunction(aValue).Result;
        if (ctrl)
          {
                    ... do something ... 
          }
     }
}
```

**MyClass Code:**

```
public class MyClass
{
   public async Task<bool> MyFontion(string aValue)
   {
      ... some code ...
      if (something)
         return true;
      else
         return false;
   }
}
```

I don't see and understand what I'm doing wrong and why when I'm getting the result it crashes the code

Thank you for your help

Comment: it might just be that your task isnt complete when you try to access the result, to drill into it we need to know what kind of exception you are getting

Comment: Sync-over-async usually leads to a deadlock - your UI thread is blocked waiting for your task to complete, but your task is blocked waiting to continue running on the UI thread. Judicious use of `.ConfigureAwait(false)` in your `MyFontion` function might help, but the real solution is to make the calling code `async` as well, and use `await` instead.

Comment: I've rewritten the code because I couldn't make the WebNavigating method async. So I've created another async method where I've put MyFuntion with await. Now it's working. Thanks for both of you for your help